# How to show attribute ID from my custom tag in source code html

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, tld, custom-tag

I have a custom tag using tld file the principal role of my tag is create a table in jsp.

The tag name is util:table and util:column in tld file I declare this tags (table and column) and some attributes as well as (id,type,name) but when I click in web page to view source code html the attributes as well as id are not display.

I need display that attribute because I need create a tooltip in determinate column using jQuery calling by id from table and column.

how to solve this ?

below my source code tag:

```
    <tag>
    <name>coluna</name>
    <tag-class>br.si.util.tags.ColunaTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
    <description>Create table</description>
    <attribute>
        <name>title</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>String</type>
        <description>title</description>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>property</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>String</type>
        <description>property</description>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>width</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>String</type>
        <description>width</description>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>type</name>
        <required>false</required>  
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>String</type>
        <description></description>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>id</name>
        <required>false</required>  
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>String</type>
        <description></description>
    </attribute>

    <attribute>
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <required>false</required>  
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>String</type>
        <description>styleClass</description>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>hidden</name>
        <required>false</required>  
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
        <type>boolean</type>
        <description>hidden</description>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>nowrap</name>
        <required>false</required>  
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>boolean</type>
        <description>nowrap</description>
    </attribute>

</tag>
```

Comment: Start by posting some code.

Comment: @developerwjk I posted code of my tag, the uniques attributes that show in viw source code are <td width='10%' align='left' nowrap='nowrap'>

Comment: That's just an XML file with a list of attributes that could be used in a tag. What makes the tag do anything?

Comment: I import this tag in my jsp and use that. But i need create a tooltip in a column from table more o attribut id are not display when transform my jsp code to html

Comment: @developerwjk you have an any idea ?

Comment: Like I said, the tld just lists attributes.  Where is the code for br.si.util.tags.ColunaTag?